# Как вывести все записи одним запросом

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица `Main` (`key` int, `filed1` int, ...) и подчиненная 
`Fields` (`id` int, `name` varchar(256)).

Имеется отношение `Main`.`filed1` -> `Fields`.`id` (или как правильно обозначать? "<-" ?).
Может быть такое, что `Main`.`filed1` = `NULL`, т.е. не для всех записей главной таблицы есть соотв. запись в подчиненной таблице.

*Задача*: нужно вывести *все* записи `Main`: `Main`.`key` AS `key`, `Fields`.`name` AS `Name`. 
Для записей `Main`.`filed1` = `NULL`, в столбце `Name` выводить `NULL`.

**UPD**
Знаю как вывести только те записи, для которых есть подчиненная запись и как вывести только те записи, для которых нету подчиненной записи. А как вывести все эти записи одним запросом?

**Решение**
Решение оказалось простым:
select `Main`.`key`, `Fields`.`Name` from `Main` left join `Fields` on `Main`.`field1` = `Fields`.`id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    LEFT JOIN 
    RIGHT JOIN
    A EXCEPT B  (забыл про него)
```

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, нужно объединить результаты двух запросов? Реальные запросы сложные и длинные.

Comment: Если вам необходимо вывести из Main айди для которых нет инфы в Fields
тогда
SELECT field1 FROM Main
EXCEPT
SELECT id FROM Fields
Вы получите такие field1 для которых нет информации в подчиененной таблице

Comment: Не то, что мне нужно было, тем не менее, спасибо, навели на решение.